# VIew items of a JSON Object

Tags: android

I've a login in android & I've mentioned Code for it. This is the PHP function file that is written in the IIS server. I get the login success as 1 which indicates login works. But, I can't go the next activity after login.

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM bpusers WHERE Email= :email ";

    $query_params = array( ':email' => $_POST['email']   );

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $validated_info = false;

    //fetching all the rows from the query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {

        if ($_POST['password'] === $row['Password']) {

        try {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {

            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Cannot register with GCM". $ex->getMessage();
            die(json_encode($response));

            }
        }
    }

    if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful to php!";

        $response["email"] = $row[Email];
            //$response["phone"] = $row[Phone_No];
            //$response["nic"] = $row[NIC];

        die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!". $ex->getMessage();;
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} 
?>
```

login.java file.

```
package cdap.park;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import cdap.billpark.dbconn.JSONParser;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText emailField, passwordField;
    private Button btnlogin;
    private Button btnforgotPwd;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String dbemail;
    String passengerID;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.4/park/passengerLogin.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public Login() {
    }

    RequestParams params1 = new RequestParams();

    Context applicationContext;

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> createRegIdTask;

    public static final String EMAIL_ID = "emailId";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(  "Location", 0);
        pref.edit().clear().commit();

        SharedPreferences prefBook = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("BookLocation", 0);
        prefBook.edit().clear().commit();

        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        // btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        // getSupportActionBar().hide();

        emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        // btnforgotPwd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        /*
         * btnforgotPwd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         * 
         * @Override public void onClick(View v) { Intent intent = new
         * Intent(Login.this, ResetPassword.class); startActivity(intent); } });
         */
        emailField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (emailField.getText().length() == 0) {

                    emailField.setError("Email Field Cannot be empty");

                }

                // int x = email.indexOf("@");
                // int y = email.indexOf(".");

            }
        });

        passwordField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                String email = emailField.getText().toString();
                if (!(email.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+"))) {

                    emailField.setError("Email is incorrect");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (passwordField.getText().length() == 0) {

                    passwordField.setError("Password Cannot be empty");
                }

                if (passwordField.getText().length() <= 2) {

                }
            }
        });
    }

    class PassengerLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
            if (pass != null && pass.length() >= 2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            int success;

            String email = emailField.getText().toString();
            String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

            String msg = "";

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",     params);

                //Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


                if (success == 1) {

                    dbemail = json.getString("email");
                    //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     Welcome.class);
                    // Create a bundle object
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    // Inserts a String value into the mapping of this Bundle
                    b.putString("email", email);
                    b.putString("password", password);
                    // Add the bundle to the intent.
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    // start the DisplayActivity
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                    editor.putString("email", dbemail);
                    editor.commit();
                    Log.e("email", dbemail);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Welcome.class);
                    i.putExtra("email", dbemail);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {

                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button:

            new PassengerLogin().execute();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following in the log cat.

```
11-12 01:09:43.058: D/json string(24238): Connected successfully
11-12 01:09:43.058: D/json string(24238): {"success":1,"message":"Login successful to php!","email":"ndp@gmail.com"}
11-12 01:09:43.058: E/JSON Parser(24238): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-12 01:09:43.088: W/dalvikvm(24238): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41689e18)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238): Process: cdap.park, PID: 24238
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at cdap.park.Login$PassengerLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:189)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at cdap.park.Login$PassengerLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-12 01:09:43.118: E/AndroidRuntime(24238):    ... 4 more
11-12 01:09:43.689: D/HardwareRenderer(24238): startTrimMemory(level >=TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity cdap.park.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41e1cb58 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:393)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:291)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at cdap.park.Login$PassengerLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:157)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at cdap.park.Login.onClick(Login.java:258)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
11-12 01:09:43.779: E/WindowManager(24238):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the NullPointerException says, your getInt fails. You should simulate the request by hand and look at the response JSON to see what's wrong.

On a somewhat related note; you are trying to start the new activity in your `doInBackground` method. This method is not intended for this, as activities can only be started from the main thread. You should do the start your activity in the `onPostExecute` method.

And finally, it looks like you save your passwords in plain text in your database. This is generally a bad idea, as an attacker could discover all passwords, should they gain access. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1054033/1659409) provides a clear description of how you should do it.